# Add an ID to n rows in dataframe and then do the same for another ID n times with R

Tags: r

I have a list of IDs and I would like add an ID into a dataframe n times, then move onto another ID like this

**ID1** 1232  4535
**ID1** 1235  4534
**ID2** 3323  3434
**ID2** 2323  2342

So here we add ID1 to two rows, then add ID2 to two rows and we would keep going like this.

Everything else will stay in the dataframe as is, but I'd like to bring an ID for each row from another dataframe, and repeat the ID for specific number of repeats and then move onto another ID, this will continue for as long as I have IDs in the list. What I was thinking was a nested loop, but I just couldn't figure out how to get this done. Any help would be great!

Comment: What if there are less/more number of ID's than the rows in the dataframe. Is repeating ID by 2 fixed or it could be any number?

Comment: It can be any number, I have few different dataframes where the number of repeats would be five, some where it would be 2 etc. But it is always fixed withing the dataframe, so if one df has 2 repeats it won't change at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be a better way to make the sequence but this works

```
data <- c("1232 4535", "1235 4534", "3323 3434", "2323 2342")

paste0("ID", sort(rep(1:(length(data)/2),2))," ", data)

[1] "ID1 1232 4535" "ID1 1235 4534" "ID2 3323 3434" "ID2 2323 2342"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rep` in this way :

```
n <- 2
df$ID <- paste0('ID', rep(1:nrow(df), each = n, length.out = nrow(df)))
df$ID
#[1] "ID1" "ID1" "ID2" "ID2"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gl` to construct an index

```
n <- 2
df$ID <- sprintf("ID%d", as.integer(gl(nrow(df), n, nrow(df)))
df$ID
#[1] "ID1" "ID1" "ID2" "ID2"
```

---

Or another option is `%/%`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate(ID = str_c('ID', (row_number()-1) %/% n + 1))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("1232 4535", "1235 4534", "3323 3434", 
"2323 2342")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```